# Two accounts de-merged; many points and top user status lost

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, user-accounts, merge-accounts

Two accounts were de-merged per [Two accounts were merged, but they were used by different people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116500/2-accounts-were-merged-different-people) but in the process, both users lost many points, and some bounties were exchanged. For example:

- Quant Guy was Top 5 in Quant Exhchange and now he has 100 points (something similar happened to him in the Economics site).
- On Stack Overflow, I lost about 500 points.
- On Quant Exchange, I recieved 2 of Quant Guy's bounties earned.

Can anyone help restore our accounts to pre-merge?

Comment: Well, Nick _did_ say "guinea pigging our new unmerge process." Calm down, I'm sure it'll get looked at now that you've reported it. (Note: I'm not a dev, and this statement is not a promise that the pre-merge data are available anymore.)

Comment: Just so I understand, you're saying that I should calm down, but there are no guarantees in a situation where I was the "lucky winner" to guinea pig a new process (without asking if I wanted to do that) and this new process reverses the merging of two accounts that were merged without my permission?  And the consequence is that two people lose many hundreds of hours?  Sorry but your "calm down" comment kind of irks me.  In the software world, I'd tell you to have more "user empathy"

Comment: Related post from Quant Guy with additional detail: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116604/lost-all-points-and-bounties-in-account-merge

Comment: @SFun28 - I think Popular Demand was just trying to state that this might take a little longer for the developers to finish the process correctly. I'm sure they're trying to make this right, but a little patience might be required in the meantime. As a side note, unless your questions and answers have been deleted, you've not lost "hundreds of hours".  Your contributions are just as valuable and helpful as they were before, whether or not you've received some virtual points for them. However, I'd expect even that to be fixed, given time.

Comment: Brad - I appreciate your comment.  I'm happy to wait for this to get fixed; I wasn't demanding immediate attention.  I posted because I think the lost points issue was lost in the de-merge post.  I agree with your comments about virtual points, but I'll also add that points are a public track-record of expertise.  At a startup company, its a great tool to build trust and confidence with potential customers.  Also, its a great way to demonstrate knowledge to employers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've recalced the unmerge (newly created) user which because of a bug didn't happen automatically.  I've also fixed up those bounties (as well as fixed the bug so *that* happens correctly in the future).

The loss in rep on either account was the result of two things:

1. Deleted content - this is (currently) normal, reputation will be corrected after a recalc, which happened here a few times...meaning votes on old now deleted posts no longer counts or appears.
2. Cross-voting between your accounts - this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) removed and will not be recovered.  Normally there should be very little cross voting between users, so this is a non-issue.  If there are exceptional posts between you that warranted upvotes, you're free to go vote again (*note:* doing so many times in a day will just result in reversal, another safety mechanism to prevent gaming the reputation system).

Sorry this didn't go so smoothly, but it was the first production test of user unmerging (something we don't *want* to have to use).  In the future be careful not to log in over-top one another, so no auto-merge triggers are hit.

Comment: Nick - thanks so much for your help with this!  Just FYI, we never log in over-top one another so maybe there's another bug?

Comment: You don't even consider that logging in carelessly may be a wrong reason to trigger a merge? Nice, I'm going to eat my colleague's account when he's out to get a coffee.

Comment: @kapep - It's not fully automated, if there's any of a dozen flags that it may be wrong, it'll appear in the a queue for us to see.  Humans aren't perfect though, neither is code...if we were, you think I'd have spent 2 weeks writing merge logging and unmerge code? :)