# lost all points and bounties in account merge

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, user-accounts, merge-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [2 accounts de-merged. Many lost points. Top user status lost](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116594/2-accounts-de-merged-many-lost-points-top-user-status-lost)

I was the top contributor for the quarter on the beta site quant.stackexchange.com with ~3700 reputation, and also had ~1000 reputation on the beta economics.stackexchange.com and also had reputation on crossvalidated and stackoverflow.

My account was merged with Sfun28 who mentions it in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116594/2-accounts-de-merged-many-lost-points-top-user-status-lost).

However, my points have reset to 100. It's frustrating to see 9 months of daily activity zeroed out while working hard to bring these exciting beta sites to life.

Please let me know when this is restored so I can get back to making contributions.

Comment: Hi there. Sfun28 [posted about this earlier](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116594/2-accounts-de-merged-many-lost-points-top-user-status-lost). I'm gonna close your question as a duplicate of his to keep the discussion in one place, but I wanted to give you a heads up here so you don't think your concerns are unfounded or ignored outright.

Comment: @AnnaLear - thanks for the heads up Anna, I appreciate it.