# Serial downvotes not being reversed?

Tags: support, serial-voting

What's going on here?

[image]

They seem to be happening in groups of four; sock puppetry possibly? This started immediately after giving some constructive feedback on a question that had received many downvotes (which was later deleted). The asker started name-calling and the downvotes started appearing on my highest-voted questions. Two days later, the downvotes appeared on my lowest-voted questions. I expected the downvotes to be reversed, but they haven't yet. This seems to be a clear-cut case of serial downvoting, even if the person doing it is using multiple accounts. Can someone look into this please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the downvotes seem to be serial-downvotes wait a day like you did. If not reversed you can flag one of the posts for moderator attention and state your concern.

Comment: Hmm, so this is not the place to handle it then?

Comment: There is no need for the community to know this specific case, since only moderators can handle such cases anyway.

Comment: @TheCommunity: pick one of the questions, Flag as Other, and give a brief description of the problem; "I believe that I am the victim of serial downvoting, 2 days of suspicious sets of 4 downvotes." Or something of the like.

Comment: Got it, will do.

Comment: "There is no need for **the community** to know" LOL :D

Comment: @TheCommunity - Saw your flag, and I warned the user responsible. I passed the voting along to the developers to get them to manually invalidate these.

Comment: @BradLarson, that sounds like a lot of trouble for a few rep points, although the questions do look odd with -1. I wonder if a feature that allowed staff to reverse chains of consecutive downvotes would be worthwhile?

Comment: @TheCommunity - [This has been proposed before](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143951/give-moderators-a-tool-to-invalidate-votes-between-users), but even though I support it there, Shog brings up some good points about the danger of allowing us to adjust votes in any way. It's probably for the best that this is difficult right now so that there's little potential for abuse.

Comment: @BradLarson thanks... FWIW, after looking at that I'm not sure I agree that moderators shouldn't have the power to do this, but I do think that in cases like this, a script could have caught it. The questions hadn't been active in a while, they all suddenly got downvoted by two IP addresses that were probably close together or the same IP, and those IP addresses probably visited my profile just before visiting those questions... I don't know if it looks at all that stuff, but I assume it could.

Comment: @TheCommunity I think that the automatic script should wait for a significant number of votes for the voting to be reversed. The flow here is quite large, so almost whatever "appears with almost-zero probablity" appears on the site, including ~10 random downvotes from a user or two, towards your answers. I know that it's annoying and de-motivating (been there too), but with 6k rep, I would say: Don't care too much and keep the good job going!