# Serial downvoting not reversed

Tags: support, voting, down-votes, serial-voting

While it's not a huge deal, I would like to see serial downvoting reversed. A couple of days ago someone decided to go through a bunch of my answers and downvote them, however the system didn't catch it. I flagged one of the downvoted answers for moderator attention and explained what happened, but nothing changed. What should I do now? Note that it's not just about the points, but it's about correcting the vote count on answers (most of which were the accepted answer).

Answer (score 5):

The next step is to contact the Team at the *Contact Us* link below.

Comment: OK, will do. I had seen this topic http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169831/serial-downvotes-not-being-reversed?rq=1 but I'll go the contact us route.

Comment: @j08691 - You could also flag again, and state that the votes weren't reversed. The initial flag was marked as helpful because we assumed the script would take care of it. The user behind this was warned, but these votes should have been invalidated. I was going to contact the devs about this, but if you've already done so, I won't worry about it. There's something odd here.