# Two actions (edit + delete) by seemingly the same user attributed to different users

Tags: support, deleted-questions, deleted-accounts, timeline

Consider these two timelines (a user cross-posted the same question, then defaced both copies):

1. https://superuser.com/posts/1730319/timeline ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFGWC.png))
2. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72891625/timeline ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qgwnh.png)).

I'm highly suspicious that all the users:

- user1702419 (now removed)
- user19392949 (now removed)
- [sarahslvmn](https://stackexchange.com/users/24883016/sarahslvmn)

...are all the accounts of one person. But how can this possible then:

[image]

<sup>pic from the Stack Overflow case, the same can be said regarding linked timeline on Super User</sup>

These two timelines are just examples, I'm more interested in *how is it technically possible in the first place* (like, what could lead to this), that a user had their account seemingly ill-removed with some attribution erased, but other staying in place

Comment: Do you know when the users were deleted? I mean, they could have deleted their posts first and then requested to nuke their accounts? That would result in the same timeline

Comment: @rene I don't know. Note the the OP ([sarahslvmn](https://stackexchange.com/users/24883016/sarahslvmn)) still has their SO and SU accounts.

Answer (score 3):

That's an interesting case! Let's review these events:

> [image]

It looks like an infamous case when a user wants to remove their content via an edit and then remove the post altogether... nothing curious, **except** for the fact that, according to common sense, all these actions should be done by one user, while they appear to be not.

So, I went ahead to check if webarchive can shed some lite on the superuser case, and yes it does, notice how the question with **the same title** was present in the **now-nuked profile**:

> [image]

Compare that to a title in a timeline:

> [image]

Which proves the fact it was the same user.

#### What could have happened then?

**Sonic's version from comments**:

> More likely cause is that the deletion vote event wasn't transferred to the new profile when it was merged, and there was no un-merge.

So, Sonic believes that a merge was done, the target account was sarahslvmn, but the delete vote was not moved to the new account, which has caused two looking-like-different users to be present in the timeline.

If we try to further dig, this actually sounds realistic, and here's why:

1. If we check Stack Overflow case, the user has removed an original post at 17:17:

> [image]

2. And immediately reposted it again, in under a minute, with the now-active account sarahslvmn ([the post is actually still alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72901922/what-is-the-best-way-to-make-a-clean-reinstall-of-python-on-windows)):

> [image]

Which means that most probably everything was done by one user deliberately, and there indeed was the merge that did not move the delete vote to the new account

**Further proof** that it's likely the correct version: compare the avatars and communities pre-merge (nuked user, [webarchive version Jul 07, 2022](https://web.archive.org/web/20220707002939/https://superuser.com/users/1702419/kerstin92)):

> [image]

And post-merge (user which currently exists and taken attribution for all these posts):

> [image]

<s>**My original super-wild version**</s>

> I cancel this version for this specific case, since I reviewed further actions of that user, see above. This doesn't mean that un-merges do not exist, they still do.

I think that it could be an unmerge action was done by a community manager ([yes it exists](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/413168)) which separated this post from the account of that user.

There're plenty of private reasons which could result in an unmerge.

A rather wild assumption, but supposing [that Open ID mess-ups have happened in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116500/two-accounts-were-merged-but-they-were-used-by-different-people), it could be that a user was accidentally merged with another one, and they couldn't wrap their head around the posts which were attributed to their account. I mean, if that was an accidental merge, then a random person suddenly realized that they own the posts he did not publish so they tried to remove them, but then a CM stepped and de-merged an account into two separate ones.

So, it could probably have been not a deface but a confused user who ended up in the account of another user.

Comment: More likely cause is that the deletion vote event wasn't transferred to the new profile when it was merged, and there was no un-merge.

Comment: @Sonic, thanks! yeah now looks like you're right, I've updated my post to include that assumption and made further digging on top of that

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog thanks, is that a bug or by design?